# Swift on Mac terminal

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, terminal

Formerly I used FreeBSD and NetBSD. Mostly I code C on Command Line Interface (CLI) with vim editor.

Now I am using macOS. As I get used to CLI, so when I code swift on macOS, I opt console.

I've learned that I can also code swift on Mac Terminal **without** installing Xcode. I can compile or interpret and run simple Swift code on Terminal.

So my questions, does swift on Mac Terminal have full features as Xcode or not? Are all Swift libraries included in Mac Terminal?

Comment: Backticks are for marking `code`, not for general *emphasis*. `Marking` all `keywords` as `code` does `not` increase `the` legibility :) – Thanks Eric!

Comment: @MartinR Thank you. I'm very new to stackoverflow. (subscribed yesterday)

Answer (score 2):

You will have to install Xcode even if you don't plan to use it, because it installs the Swift toolchain.

On Linux you can install standalone Swift (and of course you can only access Linux libraries, not macOS or iOS ones) but in macOS you have to install via Xcode (but you don't *have* to use Xcode itself to write code).

See https://swift.org/getting-started/ and https://swift.org/download/#releases

Comment: There's now [a link to](https://monosnap.com/file/LSbHFcjagmWHHDR0ix3Q1B4wQFStl2) a Swift toolchain package on [swift.org](https://swift.org/download/#releases) for macOS. I haven't tested because I already have Xcode installed, so I don't update my answer yet - but it should enable using Swift without having to install Xcode.

Answer (score 2):

Install xcode command line tools. Then in terminal, follow steps:
Step 1: Open Terminal
Step 2: Type "swift"

Now you can write swift code here. But better to use playground.